# Can someone spot my error in this integration problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem:
$$
\int \frac{dx}{(5x + 3)^5}
$$

Using u-substituition: $u = 5x + 3, du = 5 dx$, therefore $\frac{1}{5}du = dx$.

I bring out the $\frac{1}{5}$ and integrate $u^5$ to be $\frac{u^6}{6}$.

So my answer is:
$$
\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{(5x+3)^6}{6}
$$

Comment: where does the 6th power come from? Shouldn't it be -4? Is the 5x+3 in the denom??

Comment: As  for real $x,$  $$\frac{d (x^n)}{dx}=nx^{n-1}\implies \int x^mdx=\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}+C$$
Here $m=-5$

Comment: Thank y'all. I ignored the fact that u was in the denominator. Fixed it and my answer is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you forgot that your $u$ is in the denominator, not the numerator. What you actually want after substitution is:
$$
\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{u^{-4}}{-4}\\
\frac{1}{5\cdot-4\cdot(5x+3)^4} = \frac{-1}{20(5x+3)^4}+C
$$
As you did not provide limits of integration (at least I didn't see them when LaTeXing the question) there needs to be a constant of integration added.

Comment: Yes you are Andre are correct I didn't add + C. I didn't add it because I wasn't finished with the problem yet, but it is indeed needed! Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that the power rule of integration. You need the power and it can be negative positive but not -1

For problems like these try to do them in your mind.
But you can always document your thoughts! For correction.